# cannot render LocalReport vs 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I am using vs2010 and getting this error "The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded." when calling

```
renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
        reportType,
        deviceInfo,
        out mimeType,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings);
```

any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Had an old rdlc file in my project. had to change the web.config to

`add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"`

from version 9 and the controlSetup.aspx with version 9 to

`%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report classes in VS 2010 rely on the newer reporting definition. It sounds like you have a report created with an earlier version of your tooling. Try opening your report in the designer and see if it prompts you to upgrade it to the latest definition version.

Comment: Had an old rdlc file in my project. had to change the web.config to <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies> from version 9  and the controlSetup.aspx with version 9 to <%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>